# How to bind a button into a particular element in dataset in VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding

I can't seem to figure out how to bind a given element to a button on a Windows form.

When I go to `DataBindings` under the control's properties, I get a list of the columns, and then I click on one column called `ID`.

I get `ItemsBindingSource - ID`.

What is the proper syntax to choose a given element from the selected column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the current item on the **CurrencyManager**:

```
Dim cm = CType(Me.BindingContext(<DataSource>), CurrencyManager)

' This will change the current record and trigger the update of the Button.
cm.Position += 1
```

If it's an autogenerated source from a SQL table,  should be: `Me.TableBindingSource`.

To select a record based on some criteria, you can find the position of the item in the data source and set it to the manager:

```
Dim element = cm.List.OfType(Of DataRowView).Single(function(view) view.Item("Column").ToString() = "Value")

cm.Position = cm.List.IndexOf(element)
```

There are simple examples here:

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12955906)

Comment: @bcsb1001 I'll update the answer with some partial code, unfortunately the question is a bit generic to write a precise solution that's why I didn't include it.

Comment: @Uno this is great thanks for your answer! I liked the find element by criteria!